# Implementing the dictionary as a sorted singly linked list Java

Tags: java, dictionary, file-io, text-files

I have to create a dictionary where  you input a text file of 5 sentences and it takes the words in them and sorts them alphabetically using a singly linked list.  I have the text file but really need help with making them into a linked list and sorting them.  I understand how to create linked lists but I don't know how to create them from a text file and sort them.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Dictionary {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] things = {"a", "dog", "eats"};
    List<String> list1 = new LinkedList<String>();
    for(String x : things)
      list1.add(x);

    String[] things2 = {"The", "Cat", "Walks"};
    List<String> list2 = new LinkedList<String>();
    for(String y : things2)
      list2.add(y);

    list1.addAll(list2);
    list2 = null;

    printMe(list1);
    printMe(list1);
  }

  private static void printMe(List<String> l) {
    for(String b : l)
      System.out.printf("%s ", b);
    System.out.println();
  }
}
```

Comment: You are not going to get any answers unless you show some code (especially since you mention it is homework)

Comment: My code I have is importing the text file, I also have code for the linked list it is just that I don't no how to get the text file into a linked list, should I post What I have?

Comment: It says it should be sorted singly linked list so I was planning on using collection.sort.  Also shyam thanks for that, I am adding it in now

Comment: I am still working on this trying to get the output of the text file in the {} after String[] things = {};
  'String[] things = {};
  List<String> list1 = new LinkedList<String>();
  for(String x : things)
    list1.add(x);'

Answer (score 0):

Try using a [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) to read the input file

Answer (score 0):

Well, the Scanner class has methods to iterate through tokens based on a pattern you supply it.
You can supply the pattern (a regular expression) either on each call to "hasNext(Pattern)" and "next(Pattern)"  or by calling the "usePattern(Pattern)" method to set the default pattern, and using the standard "hasNext()" and "next()" iterator methods.

If you don't set any pattern it uses this:

```
// A pattern for java whitespace
private static Pattern WHITESPACE_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(
"\\p{javaWhitespace}+");
```

I won't get into the regular expressions here, but your general flow would be:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(reader);
scanner.usePattern(Pattern.compile("some regex pattern")); // if you want something other than the default
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    String word = scanner.next();
}
```

Likely reader would be an instance of java.io.FileReader.  And you want a better throughput for a large file, wrap the FileReader in a java.io.BufferedReader.

For sorting, you can either sort with Collections.sort() after adding all the words, or while adding each word, you can iterate through the existing linked list with the ListIterator returned by List.listIterator() method, find the first element which is lexigraphically greater than that token, and insert before that token using the ListIterator.add() method.